# How to express like: "first from the start or end"?

Tags: sentence-structure, question

I've split a text into 5 parts, and separated them from each other. In this way I ask students to re-arrange the fragments and ask which would be the third part of the whole text. But I did not know how to ask this in an appropriate way.
This is a text split into 5 parts, where the original arrangement has been changed.

> I. Kinder lernen Fremdsprachen wesentlich einfacher
>
> II. und schneller als Erwachsene.
>
> III. so fällt das Aneignen einer neuen Sprache einfacher.
>
> IV und Wortschatz verinnerlicht,
>
> V. Ein Kind hat die Erstsprache noch nicht so tief in Grammatik

Would my following question make any sense?

> Wenn man den Text in der richtigen Reihenfolge anordnen würde, welche würde dritte von Anfang?

Comment: "..., welcher wäre der dritte Teil von vorn?" würde ich sagen, obwohl meine praktische Erfahrung mit der Sprache gegen Null trendiert... :D

Comment: what about when I ask like following: "Mit welchem der römischen Zahlen würde dritte Teil beginnen, wenn man den Text in sinvolle und richtige Anordnung bringen würde."?

Comment: Sounds like an overkill for me. And don't forget the definite article of "Teil".

Comment: We can not say like this: "..., welcher würde der dritte Teil sein?", because there is no "würde + sein" usage, right?

Comment: It's gramatically correct, but comes hardly ever to use, since there's a simple form - "wäre".

Comment: "... welches wäre der dritte Teil? Notieren Sie die römische Zahl."

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion: "Bringen Sie den Text in die richtige Reihenfolge. An welcher neuen Position steht Teil III?" (correct answer: "am Ende" or "V")

Answer (score 1):

> Wenn man den Text in der richtigen Reihenfolge anordnen würde, welche  würde dritte von Anfang?

Your question is gramatically not correct. You could rather ask:

> Wenn man die Texte in der richtigen Reihenfolge anordnen würde, welcher wäre der dritte vom Anfang?

Or alternatively:

> Wenn man die Texte in der richtigen Reihenfolge anordnen würde, welcher stünde an dritter Stelle?

The latter sound to me as a native speaker a little better.